# Use of Intent in onChildClickListener cannot find method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, expandablelistview, onclicklistener

I have a listView with sublistView items where i referred to [Using lists in Android](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) (15.2. ExpandableListView example).

I am able to get click for each list item by Toast and display.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(activity, children,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

But when i want to use Intent in childClick, i receive an error: `cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)`.

Below is my class:

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
//Some sort of class code in here...

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
TextView text = null;

if (convertView == null) {
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_details, null);
}
text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text.setText(children);

convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
        //11 group position exist, each has 5 child
        switch ((groupPosition)){
        case 0:
        if (childPosition == 0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=editors_choice"));
            startActivity(intent); //cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)


        } else if (childPosition == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "2",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (childPosition == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "3",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else if (childPosition == 3) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "4",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (childPosition == 4) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "5",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        break;

        case 1:
        ...
  }
});
return convertView;
  }
 }
```

Thank you for helps.

Comment: Can you show when you call this class MyExpandableListAdapter  inside your activity.

Comment: if you can check the link i mentioned above maybe better for you to get wider view, otherwise i can add in my code also, no problem. Btw, i call it in my Main Activity which extends ActionBarActivity.

Comment: My concern is you can not call startActivity() inside your list adapter. it is method of your application context class.

Comment: I understand, but how i can manage this situation, i need to use this intent with child items. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent).

Because `startActivity` method is not from `BaseExpandableListAdapter` so use Context to access `startActivity` method. as:

```
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I can run the app, but it crashes when i click "No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=editors_choice }". Do you have any idea?

Comment: i changed it to package and error is: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.myapp.mapcards }

Comment: Yeah, this helped me! For the issue, emulator lacks GooglePlay, need to test on real device to access package! Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

try this,

Define a reference for Context in your MyExpandableListAdapter class ,

```
private Context context;
```

Create a constructor for your MyExpandableListAdapter class and pass the context from where you instantiate it,

```
    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context con) {
    context = con;
}
```

Start your activity with,

```
context.startActivity(intent)
```